# Can I use Xamarin test cloud with other hybrid apps?

Tags: cordova, xamarin, ionic-framework, xamarin-test-cloud

Can I use Xamarin Test Cloud with other hybrid applications (Cordova) or native applications or is it strictly for Xamarin hybrid apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your app is written with Xamarin or any other framework. **You can test it in the Xamarin Test Cloud**.

The only thing that matters is the test framework. You can use Xamarin.UITest only if your app is already written with Xamarin. Otherwise you need to use Calabash. See the graphic below.

[image: How to select the test framework]

Source: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/choosing-a-framework/

Comment: I am not sure about that. At least for Android applications I can say that it is possible to test them with Xamarin.UITest and nunit even so they are not written with Xamarin.Android.

Comment: It is possible to test any app with UITest, not just those built with Xamarin.